# Coverage with nosetests not exiting

Tags: nose, python-coverage

I have an instance of Atlassian Bamboo running that calls and creates a code coverage website using the coverage.py script.

it calls:

```
coverage run $(which nosetests)  --with-xunit $test_files
coverage html -D directory
```

Today, a user introduced a failing test and coverage never exited.

When the service account runs  this, it finishes and exits

```
 nosetests --with-xunit $test_files
```

Am I doing something wrong in how I run nosetests with coverage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ned from Coverage advised me to switch to

```
coverage run -m nose ...
```